# How to document some parameter is optional in javascript?

Tags: javascript, parameters, option-type

I have following code.

```
  // optional: itemTemplate, SubitemView, SubitemModel
        this.itemTemplate = options.itemTemplate;
        this.SubitemView = options.SubitemView;
        this.SubitemModel = options.collection.model;
```

And all those variables are actually optional.
If supplied, client can call functions which make use of those variables.

As indicated, I just put comment "Optional: ...".
I'm wondering if there is a better way to inform other programmers some variables are optional in a function?

Preferably in code. as in foo(a, b='foo') in other languages.

The above code is in backbone-view if that makes difference.

Comment: You might want to look at http://usejsdoc.org/

Comment: How (what tool, syntax?) do you document your parameters at all?

Comment: Is there a way to self-document it in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also suggest using JSDoc: [Docs](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html)

```
/**
 * @param {string} [somebody] - Somebody's name.
 */
```

This will create the optional param in the JSDoc3 syntax.  Can then generate docs using: [this](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc)